# Cannot generate Xtext artifacts for grammar which uses parentheses and cross-references at once

Tags: dsl, xtext

I'm trying to generate DSL from this grammar:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Program:
     "print" expression=Expression "where" constant=Constant  | 
     "print" expression=Expression;

Expression:
    Add;

Add returns Expression:
    Primary({Add.expression1=current} "+"  expression2=Primary)*;

Primary returns Expression:
    ExpressionParentheses | Number | ConstUsage;

Number returns Expression:
    value=INT;

Constant:
    name=ID "=" number=Number;

ConstUsage returns Expression:
    name=[Constant];

ExpressionParentheses returns Expression: 
    "(" Add ")";
```

But generating Xtext artifacts in Eclipse always produces an error. It occurs always when I'm using ExpressionParentheses and also ConstUsage in Primary rule at once. When I put there either ConstUsage or ExpressionParentheses, everything works fine. What could be the problem with my grammar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thw following grammar works fine

```
Program:
     "print" expression=Expression ("where" constant=Constant)?
;

Expression:
    Add;

Add returns Expression:
    Primary({Add.expression1=current} "+"  expression2=Primary)*;

Primary returns Expression:
    Number | ConstUsage | "("Add")";

Number returns Expression:
    value=INT;

Constant:
    name=ID "=" number=Number;

ConstUsage returns Expression:
    name=[Constant];
```

Comment: Yes, rewriting of the first rule works fine. Thanks a lot! Could you tell me please why my case of Program rule is not working correctly when I'm trying to put ConstUsage and also Parentheses expression into the Primary rule ? Thanks.

Comment: @scanyboss If I understand your comment, you want to make your Expression rule like this `Expression: Add | ConstUsage;`

Comment: No. I wanted to make Primary rule like this:

Primary returns Expression:
    ExpressionParentheses | Number | ConstUsage;

but in my original grammar was the Program rule like this:

`Program:
     "print" expression=Expression "where" constant=Constant  | 
     "print" expression=Expression;`
and it didn't work this way. But rewriting Program rule like this:

`Program:
     "print" expression=Expression ("where" constant=Constant)?;
`
helped.

My question was why my original Program rule didn't work.